# How to store the sum of a range of cells in a variable?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to store the sum of a range of cells in a variable.

```
Sub obtainhours()

Dim Total As Integer

Worksheets("22012017").Activate
Total = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("D2,D50"))

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You don't need to Activate your sheet for this purpose. Your mistake is you use "," instead of ":". Try this `Total = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Worksheets("22012017").Range("D2:D50"))`

Answer (score 0):

First, you should declare `Total` As `Long`, since it's able to store numeric values larger than `Integer` (`>32767`).

Also [Why use Long instead of Integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long)

You should avoid using `Activate` as it slows down your code's run-time, instead use fully qualified object, by implementing the `With` statement.

```
Sub obtainhours()

Dim Total As Long

With Worksheets("22012017")
    ' Option 1: get the Sum of cells "D2" and "D50" only
    Total = WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Range("D2,D50"))

    ' Option 2: get the Sum of cells "D2 through cell "D50"
    Total = WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Range("D2:D50"))
End With

End Sub
```